# Running multiple endpoints in ASP.NET Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am new to .NET Core and C#. I am trying to write a REST API application in .NET Core and I have to support multiple endpoints in same application. e.g.

**Endpoint 1**

```
https://localhost:5000/DeviceInfo
https://localhost:5000/DeviceInfo/abc
```

**Endpoint 2**

```
https://localhost:5000/location
https://localhost:5000/location/abc
```

I have a number of endpoints in the applications like this.

I want to support `GET, POST, DELETE` using an API. I am planning to implement each endpoint as a controller class. I achieved the functionality for single endpoint by writing a controller class and creating an API project in ASP.NET Core.

Now when it comes to handling multiple different endpoint in a single application, I am not sure how should I handle this so that all the endpoint should run as separate service.

Also for single endpoint handling I have selected API project not web application option while creating new project. Right now I only need to send `JSON` data on `GET` request for all endpoints .

If anyone can guide me on this that would be good start for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can write multiple controllers for different parent addresses and then create sub routes under these controllers

Comment: "all the endpoint should run as separate service", so what is your definition of service? A separate process or something else?

Comment: @Lex Li To answer your question I want to run all the endpoints parallel as independent entity so that multiple client can get data from these using REST Api.

Comment: Then you have to define "independent entity". Try not to use your own words, but common words others use, like processes, micro-services. By doing so, you don't even need to ask every questions on your own, as someone is likely to ask that long before.

Comment: @Lex Li  I agree with you here.But since I am new to c# /.netcore and due to this I am not able to explain the exact requirement. So let me put it like this .I have current application in WCF which is running as single process . But this application is using "WebServiceHost" and ServiceContract for each endpoint . Now I want to create something like that in .netcore . I am not sure whether I should call it microservice or not. Hope I am able to clear my requirement this time.

Comment: If you have two service contracts in WCF, then you probably should have two controllers in ASP.NET Core (what you do now). WCF endpoints have too many properties to configure, while a controller in ASP.NET Core only works by a few conventions (URL style, HTTP verbs, and so on). So you cannot map everything from WCF to ASP.NET Core, and something has to be dropped (and luckily they should have been dropped for simplicity). You might try to find more posts on WCF migration to Web API and ASP.NET Core for details.